# python error:list.remove(x) x not in list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was trying to compare integer from a list and remove it from the list and append it on an array with python. Every time I run my code there is an error occured.
"list.remove(x) x not in list". I can't figure it out whats happening on such an error. Can anybody give me some advice? Thank you.

```
def maxcompare(n):
   lis = map(int, n.split(','))
   threeans = []
   for i in range(3):
       maxnum = [0]
       for j in n[1:]:
           if j > maxnum:
               maxnum = j
       lis.remove(maxnum)
       threeans.append(maxnum)
   return maxnum
```

comparing integers
print out the three biggest integers
maxcompare('2,8,9,7,6,10,5')

Comment: maxnum should probably be set to `lis[0]`, rather than `[0]`

Comment: If `n` is a string, then `j > maxnum` is comparing numbers (or lists?) with strings. Not gonna work. Have you tried using just `maxnum = max(lis)`?

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Compare an integer to what?  Show a sample of your initial list, and what you want your results to be

Comment: Also, you might remove more than one number from `lis` and append it to `threeans`, but neither matters much, as both lists as discarded anyway as soon as the function is over.

Comment: @tobias_k, yes! Exactly! but the error still occured. is there anything wrong with this "lis.remove(maxnum)"?

Comment: This code has problems.  your for loop sets i to 0,1,2, but never uses i.  You have a list called n which appears out of nowhere.  The function you define is not called anywhere.  What is n?

Comment: To be brutally honest, there is _a lot_ wrong with the code, so much that I can't really see what it's _supposed_ to do. As I said, the _primary_ error is that `maxnum`, which is a list `[0]` can not possibly be in a list of `int`, thus the error.

Comment: The problem is that in python2 you can compare `int`s with `list`s and the comparison is done by comparing the *names* of the types. Since `"int" < "list"` you have that `j > maxnum` is always false and you end up calling `lis.remove([0])`. If you used python3 you'd have a `TypeError` when comparing `j` with  `maxnum`, which is more sensible.

Comment: Thanks guys, appreciated the help. I'm still a rook of this language. Guess I need to work harder.

Comment: Since you are just starting learning python: are you aware that python2.7 is **old** and dieing? You should **really** use python3. Python3 tend to have a more intuitive behaviour and to be stricter, which helps a lot when you are just starting to learn. Python2 should currently be used only if you have an already established code base that depends on packages that aren't yet available for python3 (the number of which is getting smaller and smaller).

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> def maxcompare(n):
...     return sorted( map(int,n.split(',')) )[-3:]
... 
>>> maxcompare('2,8,9,7,6,10,5')
[8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: Or you can use `heapq` which should be faster (O(n)): `import heapq; def maxcompare(n): return heapq.nlargest(map(int, n.split(',')), 3)`

Comment: @Bakuriu is heapq  heap sort?

Comment: No, it implements [heap queues](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/heapq.html). It does not *sort*. It builds the heap and then removes the number of elements you asked.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code. Try this:

```
def maxcompare(n):
   lis = map(int, n.split(','))
   threeans = []
   for i in range(3):
       maxnum = lis[0]
       for j in lis[1:]: # iterate lis, not n
           if int(j) > maxnum:  # cast j to int
               maxnum = j
       lis.remove(maxnum)
       threeans.append(maxnum)
   return threeans  # return threeans
```

This way, `maxcompare('2,8,9,7,6,10,5')` will return `[10, 9, 8]`. However, you could do the same much easier using builtin functions such as [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#max) or [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#sorted), e.g. you could replace the four lines for finding `maxnum` with just `maxnum = max(lis)`, or just sort the entire list in reverse order and return the first three elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to map to a 2D (or greater dimensional) array, it won't work because some of what you split will necessarily contain brackets. You can't take the `int` of brackets.

So given that lis is necessarily 1D, lis will never contain maxnum because that would imply that lis is a 2D array. [0, 1] does not contain [0]; [[0], [1]] does.

Also, no integer is greater than [0] in Python. `sys.maxint > [0]` returns `False`

That's why your code doesn't work.
See galaxyan's code for a pythonic and quick solution.